# Abstract class In Odmantic Model - Python FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi

I am working on a project, where all the MongoDB collections contains mandatory fields.
While modeling the same in FastAPI, I am trying to create ABC(Abstract Base Class) for mandatory fields and trying to inherit in child classes.

Issue is: Code is not considering fields in ABC class at all.

This [url](https://art049.github.io/odmantic/modeling/), says "Models can't be inherited".
My environment is: Python + FastAPI + MongoDB. I am using ODMantic for MongoDB operations.

Is there any workaround for this issue? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, they can't be inherited, but what's their use for? I don't see the real question here.

I can only make assumptions on what you may be needing:

- If you need to check the input, then `fastapi` has you backed up with `pydantic`. See https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body/?h=pydantic#create-your-data-model . You can then create the `odmantic` model passing the input as dictionary (`omodel(**model_name.dict())` or whatever name you use).
- If you want to reduce the amount of copy and paste code or want the two models to share a common base, there are docs on the link you mentioned on how to integrate it with `fastapi` https://art049.github.io/odmantic/usage_fastapi/

Apart from the two points above, I do not understand what other needs you could have. If this answer did not get you on the right path, let me know, but before please be more specific about your goal.

Comment: @Riyas user case is similar to mine. I've different Models depending on what I need to accomplish. Ex: the `CreateUserModel` have `created` and mandatory `password`. `UpdateUserModel` have `updated` one and optional `password`. The `PubblicUserModel` for the end user have none of the three. This approach with Pydantic it's quite handy, but without inheritance as Odmantic you need to duplicate the fields and it can easily became messy.